# Reuse list on another page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a problem. I've created a list like this:

```
_Results.Add(new Result(_currentQuestion.Question, choice, _currentQuestion.ImagePath));
```

Now I want to reuse this list on another page of my application.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:-

In your first page you have to declare your list as static like this:

```
public static List<T> _Result =new List<T>();
```

and add items like you are adding

```
_Results.Add(new Result(_currentQuestion.Question, choice, _currentQuestion.ImagePath));
```

step 2:-

and in other page where you want to access this list first declare list like this

```
public List<T> _result =new List<T>()
```

`_result=ClassName._Result;`- here class name will be your first page class name

and here `List<T>` - T means your list type

Comment: try with above static variable concept would help you defienetly

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction, but unfortunately I get red lines (the type or namespace could not be found) under `_Result =`. What am I doing wrong? I should replace `_result` with `ClassName._Result`, right?

Comment: i am sure my answer is correct but defenetly you are making mistake somewhere in your programme

Answer (score 0):

If you need to persist the state of `_Results` object I'd suggest you to create a `static container class`, and do whatever with it. The state will be persisted throughout your app.

```
public static class _cont
{
    public static List<Result> _Result;
}
```

But the easiest and cleaner way should be to store your `_Result` in `isolatedStorage` and retrive it whenever required. You can use `async` methods to load/store of your `_Result` object.

Answer (score 0):

Have a class like below in your namespace.

```
namespace xxx

{

public static class Result

{

    private static List<string> lstResult;

    public static List<string> LstResult

    {
             get { return lstResult; }
             set { lstResult= value; }
             }
           }
         }
```

Wherever you want use the list in you files call like this:

```
LstResult.Add("Value");
```